# MySQL InnerJoin - Unknown column on clause

Tags: mysql, join

I've been messing about with MySQL for a while, got all my db setup and now I'm trying to join the tables together with InnerJoin, but I keep getting this "Unknown column on clause" error, tried googling but my code seems to be right.

Here's what the query looks like:

```
    select 
        CharacterName, ClassName, PerkName
    FROM 
        rpgcharacter
    INNER JOIN 
        class ON rpgcharacter.idClass = class.idClass
    inner join 
        perks on rpgcharacter.idRPGCharacter = perklist.idRPGCharacter;
```

Error

> Code: 1054. Unknown column 'perklist.idRPGCharacter' in 'on clause'

Comment: Do you mean `perks.idRPGCharacter`? Or `inner join perklist`?

Comment: The perklist table is merely a table that relations the perks tabel together with the rpgchracter table

Comment: As it says the column doesn't exists show table structure and we can point to the error :)

Comment: You cannot join a table perks and try to access the table perklist.

Comment: Not even for comparing the values? I mean i'm only joining the table if it's pk is equal to a value in another table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh I see what I was doing wrong, apparently since I had not previously compared or even mentioned the query could not find the table, this is the solution I found.

```
select 
    rpgcharacter.CharacterName, class.ClassName,
    perks.PerkName, skills.SkillName
from 
    perklist
inner join 
    rpgcharacter on perklist.idRPGCharacter = rpgcharacter.idRPGCharacter
inner join 
    class on rpgcharacter.idClass = class.idClass
inner join 
    perks on perklist.idPerks = perks.idPerks
inner join 
    skilllist
inner join 
    skills on skilllist.idSkill = skills.idSkills 
           and skilllist.idRPGCharacter = rpgcharacter.idRPGCharacter
where 
    perklist.idRPGCharacter = 3
```